# Loss for Probability Density Function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Given a continuous probability density function $p(x)$ and some points $x_1, x_2, \ldots x_n$. Can you find a loss function that describes how well represented the points are by $p(x)$.

I would like the function to describe in general how likely that distribution of points was to be generated by $p(x)$. Moreover if I want the loss function to be linear in the $x_i$. Something of the form $f(x_1) + f(x_2) + \cdots + f(x_n)$ where $f$ is arbitrarily complicated.

Comment: $\prod_{i=1}^n p(x_i)$ should do the trick ... this is the likelihood

Comment: Let us say my distribution is the normal distribution with standard deviation $10$. If all my $0 < x_i < 1$, it is not that likely because values in the tails were never found.

Comment: so the in this case the reason it wouldn't be that likely is that the wider the distribution the shorter it is because of normalization ... normal distribution has normalization pre-factor proportional to $1/\sigma$ therefore, for $n$ data points, if your distribution is 3 times "too wide", your likelihood will be ~$3^n$ smaller than it ought to be

Comment: meanwhile having more of your data points in the center of the distribution actually helps the likelihood because pdf is higher in the center ... so you get penalized either way ... for a given set of points, the optimum value of the standard deviation (must be centered as well of course) will maximize the likelihood

Comment: see picture below in answer

Comment: I see. Thank you. I understand now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

example here of 8 points sampled from standard normal (mean 0 stdev 1) ...
also shown are likelihood values computed for 4-cases ... one is almost perfect ... one is right width but off center ... one is centered but two wide ... the other centered but too narrow

in each case you can see how the almost perfect case has, on average, a larger pdf value at each sampled location